# Is water released when a phosphodiester bond is made between two nucleotides during DNA replication?

Tags: biochemistry, dna-replication

I know that when two sugar molecules (like glucose) connect to each other, H<sub>2</sub>O is released because of the -OH and -H groups in both of the molecules. I want to know if the same thing happens when two nucleotides connect to each other during DNA replication.

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! What research have you done before asking it here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes there is no water release during phosphodiester linkages because the 3'OH of the growing daughter strand exerts a nucleophilic attack on the phosphodiester linkage between the alpha phosphate with the beta & gamma phoshate of the deoxyribonucleoside triphosphate.

During such formation there is no hydrolysis rather it would precisely be a transesterification type of organic reaction.

REFERENCES:TEXT BOOK OF BIOCHEMISTRY(T.M. DEVLIN)
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transesterification

Answer (score 1):

No, nucleophillic attack by the activated 3'-hydroxyl on the α-phosphate of the incoming nucleoside triphosphate results in the formation of a new phosphodiester bond and release of pyrophosphate (PPi), which is subsequently hydrolyzed.

[image]

[[image source](https://chem.libretexts.org/Textbook_Maps/Organic_Chemistry_Textbook_Maps/Map%3A_Organic_Chemistry_with_a_Biological_Emphasis_(Soderberg)/10%3A_Phosphoryl_transfer_reactions/10.4%3A_Phosphate_diesters)]